# Can't rescale drawable in button

Tags: java, android

```
private float iconScale = 0.05f;    
// Set size of drawables in buttons
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cutlerywhite);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()),
        (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, iconScale, iconScale);

fnbButton.setCompoundDrawables(sd, null, null, null); //set drawableLeft for example
```

I'm trying to scale down a drawable for use in a `Button`. Right now, nothing is showing up in my button:

[image]

There should be a drawable on the left.
What's the problem here? I've done exactly as I've seen others do in various answers on here.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fnbButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_blue"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/fnb_button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/otherButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your cutlerywhite and button layout?

Comment: Added xml for the button. cutlerywhite is just an image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this option will help

```
   private void useScaledDrawableLeft(Button buttonView, float scale, @DrawableRes int imageResource) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(imageResource);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bd.getBitmap(),
                (int) (bd.getIntrinsicHeight() * scale),
                (int) (bd.getIntrinsicWidth() * scale),
                false);

        BitmapDrawable scaleDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(b);
        buttonView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(scaleDrawable, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Where do you recommend I call this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cutlerywhite);
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, Gravity.CENTER, iconScale, iconScale);
Drawable d1 = sd.getDrawable();
d1.setLevel(1);
sd.setLevel(1);
fnbButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(sd, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
Drawable drawableFnb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cutlerywhite);
Drawable drawableSunbed = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logowhite);

ScaleDrawable sdFnb = new ScaleDrawable(drawableFnb, Gravity.LEFT, 1, 1);
ScaleDrawable sdSunbed = new ScaleDrawable(drawableSunbed, Gravity.LEFT, 1, 1);
Drawable d1 = sdFnb.getDrawable();
Drawable d2 = sdSunbed.getDrawable();

Dims fnbDims = getIconDims(drawableFnb);
Dims sunbedDims = getIconDims(drawableSunbed);

d1.setBounds(0, 0, fnbDims.getWidth(), fnbDims.getHeight());
d2.setBounds(0, 0, sunbedDims.getWidth(), sunbedDims.getHeight());

fnbButton.setCompoundDrawables(d1, null, null, null);
sunbedButton.setCompoundDrawables(d2, null, null, null);
```